# Finding distance and other values in query

Tags: iphone, ios7

Trying to find the distance and other values of table in query in sqlite. If i try with only distance it works, bit with other value the control goes out of the sqlite statement.

This is the query that doesn't work:

```
SELECT Radius, distance(Latitude, Longitude, %f, %f) FROM tbLocations
```

That works is:

```
SELECT distance(Latitude, Longitude, %f, %f) FROM tbLocations
```

What is wrong above, Please guide.